# How to create a selector that has x but not y selector

Tags: jquery

Given the following two elements, how can I create a jquery selector that selects the first but not the second:

```
<a href="" class="x">First element</a>

<a href="" class="x y">Second element</a>
```

I have tried the following, but it does not seem to be working for me:

```
$(".x").not(".y").on("click", alert('first')); //should select First Element
$(".x.y").on("click", alert('second'));  //should select the Second Element
```

Thanks!

Comment: Both of your examples should work if you use the handler correctly - you need an anonymous function with the `alert` - right now it should just be alerting on page load

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(".x").not(".y").on("click", function(){alert('first');}); //should select First Element
$(".x.y").on("click",function(){ alert('second');});  //should select the Second Element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="x">First element</a>

<a href="#" class="x y">Second element</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add function after `"click"` and don't forget to add jQuery.

```
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

$(".x").not(".y").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('First');
});

$(".x.y").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('second');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something where class is only "x" you can do this:

```
$('[class="x"]')
```